# Use OVER or LAG functions to COUNT the number of orders in a ROLLING five day period?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, window-functions, rolling-computation

I want to Count the Orders in a rolling 5 days, after Partitioning BY Customer and ordering by Orderdate.

My goal is to identify high volume and/or potentially fraudulent accounts. Find all the customers that had X  orders within 5 any days.

I am using SQL Server (SSMS v17.9.1) in Win10.

I've tried using OVER with Range and DATEADD, but received an error  "Incorrect syntax near DATEADD.  Expected CURRENT, INTEGER or UNBOUNDED".

I tested the OrderDate field with a calculated field subtracting 5 days (DateMinus5), just to be sure the date field is ok.

My code generated the error "Incorrect syntax near DATEADD.  Expected CURRENT, INTEGER or UNBOUNDED".

```
SELECT [SalesOrderID]
  ,[OrderDate]
  ,[CustomerID]
  ,COUNT(*) OVER (Partition BY [CustomerID] RANGE BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, 
  -5, [Orderdate]) AND CURRENT ROW)

FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]

╔═══════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════╗
║ Sales OrderId ║        OrderDate        ║        DateMinus5       ║ CustomerId ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 43659         ║ 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 ║ 2005-06-26 00:00:00.000 ║ 29825      ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 43660         ║ 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 ║ 2005-06-26 00:00:00.000 ║ 29672      ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 43661         ║ 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 ║ 2005-06-26 00:00:00.000 ║ 29734      ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 43662         ║ 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 ║ 2005-06-26 00:00:00.000 ║ 29994      ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 43663         ║ 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 ║ 2005-06-26 00:00:00.000 ║ 29565      ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Do you want, in the single query, the output of previous 5 day periods or just the current past 5 days worth of data? If so, then a group by on customerid should be sufficient here.

Comment: You can use a subquery or `cross apply`

Comment: MindingData: I am looking to add a column with the COUNT for each line in the report. Sometimes it could be zero.  I know this works with Rows unbounded etc... but haven't seen it with a date interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader o CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader o2
    WHERE o2.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
       AND o2.OrderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -5, o.OrderDate) AND o.OrderDate
) lg
WHERE cnt >= X;
```

Comment: Thank you. Excuse my "newbieness"... With the CROSS APPLY, I don't need to define how it's joined, i.e. like  "on"  with a Left Join etc....

Comment: @eli No, but notice that it's correlated in the `where` clause though.

Comment: Is it because this is a self join?

Comment: @eli No, you could have written it as a self join. This is a bit more convenient.